# Error: missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: c#

```
protected void gvdet_DataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    string employeeName = dsOLDData.SelectedItem.Text; -- ERROR HERE :(

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

        foreach (TableCell c in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            if (c.Controls[0] is DataBoundLiteralControl)
            {
                DataBoundLiteralControl ctl = (DataBoundLiteralControl)c.Controls[0];
                if (ctl.Text.Contains(employeeName))
                {
                    c.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                    c.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
                }
            }

        }
    }
  }
}
```

ERROR:
Error   2   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinqDataSource' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedItem' and no extension method 'SelectedItem' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinqDataSource' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What is dsOLDData? Is it a data set? Dropdown list?  We need more detail or we can't help you.

Comment: Hi David, I appreciate the editing.  Hope I can get a helpful solution.

Comment: Yes David, it is a dropdown list

Comment: I pick an employee from ddl and it will show a gridview details and colored the employee name ONLY to the gridview list that I picked from the dd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you really sure, "dsOLDData" is a Dropdownlist. The errormessage seems to say it's an instance of System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinqDataSource

The "ds" at the beginning of "dsOLDData" would be a sign for me, too, that it's a **D**ata **S**ource

Comment: Hi Peter,
You're right I mistakenly put my datasource instead of the ddl.  Thanks - good eye.

Comment: Yonita, do you now understand what that error message was telling you? It's a very common error message. It will be very helpful to you if you learn what it means.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling DataBind on your DropDownList before accessing it's selected item. It may not have bound to any data at the point your GridView does. eg.

```
dsOLDData.DataBind();
string employeeName = dsOLDData.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Not sure if that will help, but worth a go...